# Property List Misused with \cs_set ... but not with \NewDocumentCommand?

Tags: expl3, latex3

In working to understand `expl3` a bit better, I came across a `property list was misused` error that I don't understand.

#### Code concept:

Create a macro (`\MarkAndSave`) that will add a visual mark (`\S` here) to the text, perhaps to signify a comment or todo of some sort.  Also, save this mark to a property list so that at the end we have a list of marks for any given page.

#### Problem:

In full disclosure, this is somewhat of a solved problem: If I define the macro with `\NewDocumentCommand`, I get no errors....

```
\NewDocumentCommand {\MarkAndSave} {} {...}
```

But I thought I would use the `expl3` syntax to define the macro:

```
\cs_set:Npn \MarkAndSave {...}
```

In this case, I get various errors along the lines of this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           A property list was misused.
l.35 \subsection{\MarkAndSave In a Subsection}
```

But the error is not consistent:

- No error: `\MarkAndSave` used only once (anywhere)
- No error: `\MarkAndSave` used in section headings without being used in paragraph text
- No error: `\MarkAndSave` used only in paragraph text without being used in headings
- Errors: `\MarkAndSave` used in a heading after being used in paragraph text

So, my question is a bit two-fold:

1. What could be the reason why the error pops up only in specific cases like this?, and
2. What does `\NewDocumentCommand` do that prevents these errors? ... or, what I am doing wrong with `expl3`?

#### MWE (TeXLive 2021):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_clear_new:N \g_cslstr_proplist
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn {Nxn}

%% If defined with NewDocCommand, works everywhere
% \NewDocumentCommand {\MarkAndSave} {} {%
%% If defined with cs_set, does not work in some headings
\cs_set:Npn \MarkAndSave {%

    % Output the mark
    \S
    % Register this mark in the list for this page
    \prop_put:Nxn {\g_cslstr_proplist}
        {page\arabic{page}}
        {Marked}
    % Debug output
    \prop_log:N \g_cslstr_proplist
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\section{\MarkAndSave In a Section}

Play around with the ordering and marked / not marked lines to see errors.

Not a marked paragraph.

\MarkAndSave A marked paragraph.

\section{\MarkAndSave Property List Misused if in heading following a marked paragraph}

Not a marked paragraph.

\subsection{\MarkAndSave In a Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: commands defined with \NewDocumentCommand are robust. That means they don't break when used in  sectioning command. On the expl3 level you could use `\cs_new_protected:Npn \MarkAndSave`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, that appears to be the simple explanation that I couldn't see :)